# Can only execute WordPress Shortcode once per page

Tags: wordpress, function, simple-html-dom, shortcode

I've written the following shortcode which for all intensive purposes *does work*, however it only works *once* per page. If i try to add the shortcode more than once then nothing after the shortcode within `the_content();` is output.

```
add_shortcode('some_shortcode', 'some_shortcode');

function some_shortcode($atts, $content = null){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "url" => ''
  ), $atts));
  require_once get_parent_theme_file_path( '/simple_html_dom.php' );
  $html = file_get_html($url);
  foreach($html->find('div.matchbox') as $match) {

    $item['time']       = $match->find('div.time', 0)->plaintext;

    $matches[] = $item;
  }
  return '<hr><p>' . $url . '</p><p>' . $item['time'] . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Sounds like the 2nd one is fatal erroring. Turn on debugging and try to get an error message. Also, it's "for all intents *and* purposes".